# Setting default category base on theme activation

Tags: php, categories, options

I'm trying to set a custom category base upon theme activation which also don't allow user to change it. If user tries to change it, it'll just gets back to "genre". Here's my code so far:

```
if (get_option('category_base') == '') {
update_option( 'category_base', 'genre' );
}
else { update_option( 'category_base', 'genre' ); 
}
```

And since im newbie in php & wordpress, I just need some words. Is it correct? If yes or not, how can i improve it?

Thanks!